# Json to excel file convert using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, excel

Please find the following code for more information.

```
function dataToCSVTry(arr) {
    var fileName = "CSVFile";
    var data = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    data += (arr[i].id + " , " + arr[i].time + "\r\n");
    }
    var url = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,' + encodeURI(data);
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    window.download = (url + ".txt");

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(url);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
    link.click();
  };
```

`

This is a function to which I'm providing JSON data as input and after that trying to convert it in to a CSV(Comma Separated Values) using a for loop.
After that i am trying to save it in both .txt and .csv format. As .txt is getting saved easily, the problem comes in excel file where the data comes like :

```
 "1%20%2C%20161.963%0A%0D%0A2%20%2C%20473.222%0A%0D%0A3%20%2C%20error%0A%0D%0A"
```

where some code (from what I think) is for blank space(`"%20%2C%20"`) and some other code(`"%0A%0D%0A"`) is for newline characters. What needs to be done in order to create Excel file in the same CSV format? Is there any problem with the `encodeURI` part that I am using ?

Answer (score 0):

Data url content isn't URI encoded, it is base-64 encoded. You should use [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) or a similar solution to create your data from the CSV string you built.